# Is heat exchange possible between two surfaces with same temperatures but different emissivities?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is heat exchange possible between two surfaces with same temperatures but different emissivities ?

Comment: No - that's pretty much the definition of same temperature

Comment: @MartinBeckett Although kind of trivial to a professional physicist, the question and your answer are an important fundamental point - I'd recommend you make your comment an answer.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Do you mean net heat transfer ? Both the surfaces will emit according to Stephan-Boltzmann law. e.g. If 100 joules of heat is transferred from surface 1 to surface 2, every 1 second, simultaneously 100 joules of heat will be transferred from surface 2 to surface 1, every 1 second. Since there is no change in the amount of joules (heat content) for each surface, their temperatures will be the same. All this is under the assumption that these two surfaces interact with each other and nothing else in the universe. Am I correct?